# Problem with WordBoundary in string patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am trying to extract from a string all words that end with "-man", but the problem is that `WordBoundary` does not seem to work as it returns whole string ignoring actual word boundaries.

Here is the code:

```
mystring = "I am a big fan of Superman, Spiderman and Batman.";
StringCases[mystring, WordBoundary ~~ __ ~~ "man"];
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem does not lie with `WordBoundary`, it is due to the use of `__`.

The string pattern `WordBoundary ~~ __ ~~ "man"` will find a word boundary properly, but then will match a following sequence of characters up to `"man"` without restriction -- *including characters that lie on word boundaries themselves*.  To exclude that possibility, we should restrict the characters between `WordBoundary` and `"man"` to be word characters:

```
StringCases[mystring, WordBoundary ~~ WordCharacter.. ~~ "man"]

(* {"Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman"} *)
```

**Some Fiddly Details...**

Consider the following:

```
mystring2 = "I like Superman, Spiderman and Batman.  But adamantly not 3man!";

StringCases[mystring2, WordBoundary ~~ WordCharacter.. ~~ "man"]

(* { "Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman", "adaman", "3man"} *)
```

`"3man"` was picked up properly, but we probably don't want to see `"adaman"` in the list.  This is easily corrected:

```
StringCases[mystring2, WordBoundary ~~ WordCharacter.. ~~"man" ~~ WordBoundary]

(* { "Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman", "3man"} *)
```

**... and a Bug**

Now, consider this:

```
mystring3 = "Remember Underscore_man!";

StringCases[mystring3, WordBoundary ~~ WordCharacter.. ~~"man" ~~ WordBoundary]

(* {} *)
```

Strange... why didn't the legendary `Underscore_man` appear in the result?  We find the answer in the documentation for [WordCharacter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCharacter.html): it represents a letter or digit character.  Fair enough.  But, wait...

```
StringCases["Dash-man & Underscore_man", WordBoundary ~~ Shortest@__ ~~ WordBoundary]

(* { "Dash", "-", "man", " & ", "Underscore_man" } *)
```

I thought that only letters and digits were word characters?  But apparently an underscore does not create a word boundary even though it is not a word character.  How can this be?

Let's take a look at the regular expressions generated for `WordCharacter` and `WordBoundary`:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[WordCharacter ~~ WordBoundary] // First

(* (?ms)[[:alnum:]]\b *)
```

We can see that `[[:alnum:]]` is being used for `WordCharacter`, in conformance to the statement in the documentation.  However, we see that `\b` is being used for `WordBoundary`.  The [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) tells us that `\b` represents adjacent word and non-word characters, and that word characters are letters, digits *or underscore*.

This means that in *Mathematica*, there is a mismatch between the definition of `WordCharacter` and `WordBoundary`.  A small bug, to be sure, but beware.

Comment: Finally an answer that said everything I was going to, *plus* an interesting analysis of WordBoundy. +1 :-)

Comment: @WReach Another small bug: `Intersection[{"Batman", "Spiderman", "Superman"}, DictionaryLookup["*man"]]`

Comment: @eldo Marvel licenses aren't cheap. :)

Comment: Note, that some non-letter characters are `LetterCharacters` and are not considered `WordBoundary`: `{StringReplace["aǁa a|a", WordBoundary ~~ "a" ~~ WordBoundary -> "A"], StringMatchQ["ǁ", LetterCharacter]}`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason to use `WordBoundary`, but your example sentence doesn't bring it out. Consider

```
mystring = "I am a demanding fan of Superman, Spiderman and Batman.";

StringCases[mystring, LetterCharacter ... ~~ "man"]
```

> ```
> {"deman", "Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman"}
> ```

so you might prefer

```
StringCases[mystring, LetterCharacter ... ~~ "man" ~~ WordBoundary]
```

> ```
> {"Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In your example `StringCases` works as expected because by default it searches the `Longest` substring which matches the pattern `__` (by default all repeated string patterns are *greedy*). Apparently the whole string without ending "." matches your pattern:

```
In[21]:= mystring = "I am a big fan of Superman, Spiderman and Batman.";
substr = StringCases[mystring, WordBoundary ~~ __ ~~ "man"]
StringMatchQ[substr, WordBoundary ~~ __ ~~ "man"]
```

> ```
> Out[22]= {"I am a big fan of Superman, Spiderman and Batman"}
>
> Out[23]= {True}
> ```

One way to restrict the pattern for matching only single words ending with "man" is to use `LetterCharacter` instead of "any character" `_`:

```
In[24]:= StringCases[mystring, WordBoundary ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ "man" ~~ WordBoundary]
```

> ```
> Out[24]= {"Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman"}
> ```

Note that switching to *lazy* version (`Shortest`) of the repeated pattern does not give the desired result:

```
In[25]:= StringCases[mystring, Shortest[WordBoundary ~~ __ ~~ "man" ~~ WordBoundary]]
```

> ```
> Out[25]= {"I am a big fan of Superman", ", Spiderman", " and Batman"}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To steal examples from the page:

```
str1 = "I am a big fan of Superman, Spiderman and Batman.";
str2 = "I am a demanding fan of Ironman, Superman and other man-made \
fiction";
str3 = "I like Superman, Spiderman and Batman.  But adamantly not \
3man!";
str4 = "Remember Underscore_man!";
```

---

Define:

```
f[str_] := Module[{words = Echo@TextWords[str]},
  Select[StringEndsQ[_ ~~ "man"]][words]
  ]

f /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4}
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman"}, {"Ironman",    "Superman"},
> {"Superman", "Spiderman", "Batman",    "3man"}, {"Underscore_man"}}

Comment: Users can remove `Echo` if debugging is not needed.